# NetBeans doesn't register my new code template abbreviation

Tags: netbeans

I am using the latest version of NetBeans (8.0), and I am trying to add my own code templates (`Tool -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates -> New`

I have created a new PHP code template with abbreviation `mn`. I click apply, and then when I go to edit my php file, the abbreviation does not bring up the code template. However, if I type one of the pre-defined abbreviations, then it works fine.

I have tried closing the PHP file and re-opening it. I have tried restarting the IDE, and I have also tried exporting and importing the code templates. Nothing will make my new abbreviation work.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes too late, but maybe this solution is useful for new users with the problem "***netbeans code template not working***" in newer versions

```
C:\Users\{yourUser}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\Editors\text\x-php5\CodeTemplates\org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomCodeTemplates.xml
```

and add this:

```
contexts="php-code"
```

in all codetemplate like this:

```
<codetemplate abbreviation="{YourAbrebiation}" contexts="php-code" xml:space="preserve">
```

restart your IDE after that and your new template will work perfectly...